# Can a view file request data from the database?

Tags: model-view-controller, phalcon, volt

This is a general MVC question but the specific framework I am using is [PhalconPHP](https://phalconphp.com/en/). In this the view files are `.volt` files - *Volt* is the template engine used by Phalcon.

Can one of these `.volt` files request data from the database (e.g. is there a command in Volt to make the request)? We want to allow the admins of the site (logged in) to edit the `.volt` files themselves in the browser but wanted to first check that Volt does not have any functionality that allows it to get data from the database, e.g. any data accessible in the `view` file must have been passed by the `controller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if I remember correctly Volt has access to the dependency injector, including the database connection.

Also you can embed `<?php` tags in volt templates.

Comment: Ah, very true. Is there anyway in which it would be possible to have a view file that cannot access the database? Editing the files in the browser would be really useful to us but we obviously don't want to allow someone who guessed the admin password to be able to add malicious code.

Comment: Depending on what you are using it for you might be able to use a different `Volt` instance with a different dependency injector. But then you might not be able to call methods on models. Or you could try a different template engine.

Comment: I was just thinking the same. Going to try using a `Volt` instance with a different `DI` and then sanitize the input before saving (stripping out php tags and anything between them). Thanks